# Comparing two Astropy Tables, based on a condition related to specific columns

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

My apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything exactly like this myself.

I have two Astropy tables, let's say X and Y. Each has multiple columns but what I want to do is to compare them by setting various conditions on different columns.

For example, table X looks like this and has 1000 rows and 9 columns (let's say):

| Name_X (str) | Date_X (float64) | Date (int32) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GaiaX21-116383 | 59458.633888888886 | 59458 | ... |
| GaiaX21-116382 | 59458.504375 | 59458 | ... |

and table Y looks like this and has 500 rows and 29 columns (let's say):

| Name_Y (str14) | Date_Y (float64) | Date (int32) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GaiaX21-117313 | 59461.911724537036 | 59461 | ... |
| GaiaX21-118760 | 59466.905173611114 | 59466 | ... |

I want to compare the two tables- basically, check if the same 'Name' exists in both Tables. If it does, then I treat that as a "match" and take that entire row and put it in a new table and discard everything else (or store them in another temp Table).

So I wrote a function like this:

```
def find_diff(table1, table2, param): # table1 is bigger, param defines which column, assuming they have the same names;
    temp = Table(table1[0:0])
    table3 = Table(table1[0:0])
    for i in range(0, len(table1)):
        for j in range(0, len(table2)):
            if table1[param][i] != table2[param][j]:
#                 temp.add_row(table2[j])
#             else:
                table3.add_row(table1[i])
    return table3
```

While this in principle, works, it also takes a huge amount of time to finish. So it simply isn't practical to be running the code this way. Similarly, I want to apply other conditions for other columns (cross-matching the observation dates, for example).

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful, thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? I believe you would be able to perform a merge/join/concate on this table depending on what you are trying to do, but if you added some of the 2 tables data and what you expect from the code it would be easier to get you exactly what your looking for.

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn, I just edited my original question a bit. Hope that helps answer your data. And thanks! :)

Comment: In case it helps, what you are looking for is called a "join" in computer science / database parlance. Specifically it sounds like you probably want an "inner join"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a table join on the name columns. This can be done as documented at https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html#join.

E.g.

```
# Assume table_x and table_y
from astropy.table import join
table_xy = join(table_x, table_y, keys_left='Name_X', keys_right='Name_Y')
```

As a full example with non-unique key values:

```
In [10]: t1 = Table([['x', 'x', 'y', 'z'], [1,2,3,4]], names=['a', 'b'])

In [11]: t2 = Table([['x', 'y', 'y', 'Q'], [10,20,30,40]], names=['a', 'c'])

In [12]: table.join(t1, t2, keys='a')
Out[12]: 
<Table length=4>
 a     b     c  
str1 int64 int64
---- ----- -----
   x     1    10
   x     2    10
   y     3    20
   y     3    30
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! But I don't think that accurately does what I want because there could be non-unique values in the key column. In that case, the numbers of all the matching rows gets mixed up.

Comment: @SumedhaBiswas - non unique key values are not a problem, see the updated answer with a new example that illustrates this.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this site would be your best friend for this problem: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

So in theory I believe you would want something like this:

```
result = pd.merge(table_y, table_x, on="Name")
```

So the key difference here would be that you might need to play with the column names for the tables so that they have the same name. What this will do though is it will match on the "Name" column between the two tables and if they are the same then it will put it in the results variable. From there you can do whatever you would like with the dataframe

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response! The column names are fine and adjustable but the real problem is dealing with non-unique key column values. So when it's matching the two tables and merging it, the rows get all jumbled up and that isn't what I can work with.

Comment: If the keys are not unique then how do you know that what key goes with what date?

Comment: I edited the original table in my question a little bit. So while the 'Name' is unique, I can use your method. 

But for example, if I want to match it with the 'Date', the values are non-unique. So in that case, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: This can be done in Astropy (without using pandas) as the original poster was asking.